# Clear button on addentry page doesn't work

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

This is my addentry blog page which I have made from scratch and there are underlying problems with this code particularly the clear button which is supposed to clear any text entered when the button is clicked on it doesn't work I have saved it as a html file is that the problem.

Also one other problem is the submit button it works but it doesn't pass any of the text to the index file I have written this as php and for some reason it whenever I click on the submit button it just redirects me back to the index page without posting the entry I have made.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script>
function message() {
    alert("Clear the form?");
}
</script>

<style>
body {background-color: beige;}
h1   {color: black;}
p    {color: black;}

textarea
{
    width: 50%;
    height: 150px;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
    resize: none;
}


div
{
    padding-left: 20px;
}

</style>
</head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../main.css">
<title>Add an entry</title>
</head>

<body>

<div><h1>Add an entry</h1></div>
<div><p><b>Enter the title of the entry so the topic is clearly defined and then add the entry for the blog that you want to write about after finishing writing about your topic press the submit button to submit the entry which will be posted in the main page of the blog however if you wish to discard or clear your entry then press the clear button to remove your topic which you have written about.</b></p></div>


<form onreset="message()">
    <p><label>Title</label>
    <input type = "text" id = "myText"/></p>

    <p><label>Entry</label>
    <textarea>
<input type="clear">
</form>



<form>
    <p><label>Title</label>
    <input type = "text" id = "myText"/></p>

    <p><label>Entry</label>
    <textarea>

    </textarea></p>

</form>


<form method="post" action="index.html">
<button type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>  <input type="button" value="Clear" onclick="javascript:eraseText();">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Particularly this part of the clear button code:

```
<script>
    function message() {
        alert("Clear the form?");
    }
</script>

<form onreset="message()">
    <p><label>Title</label>
    <input type = "text" id = "myText"/></p>

    <p><label>Entry</label>
    <textarea>
    <input type="clear">
</form>
```

And this is the submit button code:

```
<form method="post" action="index.html">
    <button type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>
    <input type="button" value="Clear" onclick="javascript:eraseText();">
</form>
```

Comment: `<button type="reset">blah</button>` or `<input type="reset" value="blah" />`... it also looks like you've got an input inside a textarea so I cannot guarantee whats going to happen there

Comment: `action="index.html"` did you treat that html file to run as php here?

Comment: As Dale has pointed out you can use `reset` but also in the source code you have shown `eraseText()` doesn't exist...

Comment: and all your `message()` JS function does is alert. It's back to the drawing board for you.

Answer (score 0):

1) Just use input field with `type="reset"` it will clear the form

2) all your input field should be same form then only it will post to next page

note : your using more than one form and expecting other form values on index page.

```html
<form method="post" action="index.html">
   
  <label>Title</label>
    <input type = "text" name="mytext" id ="myText"/>
<br>
<br>
  <label>Entry</label>
    <textarea name="area"> </textarea>
<br>
<br> 
   <button type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>
    <input type="reset" value="Clear" >
</form>
```